# I am not able to create these containers in Oracle Cloud

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, cloud

I receive the following error:

WARNING: The requested image is platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

```yaml
#!/bin/bash

version: "3.7"

services:
  db:    
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Root193782"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "test"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    
    restart: always

    networks:
      - mysql-network

  phpmyadmin:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Root193782"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /data/php/admin/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini

    networks:
      - mysql-network

networks:
  mysql-network:
```